# Is it possible to use custom variables in an extjs store?

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4, store

Currently I am working on a project using ExtJs (Version 5.0.1).
Now since I often create stores, I wanted to create some kinde of template to copy or may even extend from.

So I was annoyed to edit the path everytime and created variable above `let controller` (before I used **const**, but since more than one store was called, it ended up in some errors)

```
let controller = "path/to/my/controller/myController.php";

Ext.define("xxx.store.foo.bar.myStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    model: "xxx.model.foo.bar.myModel",
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        timeout: 20000,
        api: {
            read: controller + "?data=read",
            create: controller + "?data=create",
            update: controller + "?data=update",
            destroy: controller + "?data=delete",
        },
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            rootProperty: "data",
            idProperty: "id",
            totalProperty: "total",
        },
        writer: {
            type: "json",
            encode: true,
            writeAllFields: true,
            rootProperty: "data",
            idProperty: "id",
        },
    },
    autoLoad: false,
});
```

How ever, I am not happy with this and would prefer some kine of internal variable. Something like:

```
Ext.define("xxx.store.foo.bar.my", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    model: "xxx.model.foo.bar.my",
    myControllerPath: "this/is/my/path/to/my/controller",
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        timeout: 20000,
        api: {
            read: this.myControllerPath + "?data=read",
            create: this.myControllerPath + "?data=create",
            update: this.myControllerPath + "?data=update",
            destroy: this.myControllerPath + "?data=delete",
        },
        ....
```

But `this.` can't be used there like this! (obviously)

What could be a solution for my problem...how could I use a custom variable there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to add a custom property for the controller path to a template store class definition, and use a `constructor` to set the proxy based on this path. This way you will already be able to use `this` keyword. Later you use this template to define your store classes.

See this code, I hope it helps:

```
Ext.define("MyStoreTemplate", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    myController: null,
    constructor: function (config) {
        this.setProxy({
            type: "ajax",
            timeout: 20000,
            api: {
                read: this.myController + "?data=read",
                create: this.myController + "?data=create",
                update: this.myController + "?data=update",
                destroy: this.myController + "?data=delete",
            },
            reader: {
                type: "json",
                rootProperty: "data",
                idProperty: "id",
                totalProperty: "total",
            },
            writer: {
                type: "json",
                encode: true,
                writeAllFields: true,
                rootProperty: "data",
                idProperty: "id",
            },
        });
    },
    autoLoad: false,
});

Ext.define("MyModel", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
});

Ext.define("MyStore", {
    extend: "MyStoreTemplate",
    myController: "path/to/my/controller/myController.php",
    model: "MyModel",
});

const myStore = Ext.create("MyStore");

console.log(myStore.getProxy());
```

Comment: this kind of looks like the thing i want to achive... i will test this tomorrow and of course accept this answere if this works. in any case, ill get back to you :)

Comment: So i could not wait to test it and started up my pc again. How ever... this results in some kinde of error with schema null. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'schema')`

Comment: I have tried in a Sencha Fiddle and it worked. Could you create an example in Sencha Fiddle to demonstrate the error you receive? For example the model does exist?

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3qe5), run it and you will see the log on the console, and no errors.

Comment: Actually i cant demonstrate the error in a fiddle since there are a lot of elements sticking to it. In this case the store is loaded in a grid with an searchfield. so this causes a problem...`(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setRemoteFilter'))` if i comment out the search, than the schema error appears. It seams like the regular store does even more and when using the constuctor, this takes some away from its regular behavior... could this be the case?

Comment: Could you add `this.callParent(config);` to the custom constructor? You could try putting it before and after the `this.setProxy` part and see if it helps. Maybe add it at the end, so that the configuration is already complete.

Comment: I am almost there :D When I comment out the search, I loads everything. And it seams to work. But since I have to use the searchfield, something still is missing. But I still will except the answere since it actually works.

Comment: I finally made it. obiously the store wasnt loaded at that point... i changed `store: "myStore"` to `store: { type: 'myStore' }` and this works.

Comment: I am happy I could help. Yes, `store: "myStore"` is incorrect, this has to be an already existing store or a type as you wrote, and ExtJS will create it by the alias provided here.

Comment: But unsing ID will always use the same store, type could create multiple instances?!?!? If I understand this right.

Comment: If you use `type: "myStore"`, a new store instance of that type will be generated . If you set `store: myStore` where `myStore` refers to an existing store, that will be used and not a new one. There are also chained stores which can share the loaded data for example but differ in sorting and filtering.

Comment: A good way to manage stores is to define them under `stores:` in your view model and use `bind` in the view class to attach these.

Comment: Could you point out a sample? this would be very nice.

Comment: A sample for what? View model binded store?